# Value expression for the query parameter contains an error; Conversion from type Object() to type 'String' is not valid

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I am running into this error when trying to execute a report.  I am passing a multi-valued parameter (OrderNo), and cannot get it to work.  the parameter is an order #, and the query takes that # and spits back some information about that order and places it on a report.

Currently, my parameter allows multiple values, and populates the available values through a query.

In my Dataset query, my where statement says:

```
WHERE x.order_no IN (@OrderNo)
```

My Dataset parameter Value is:

```
=SPLIT(Parameters!OrderNo.Value, ",")
```

All I need is for this query to return multiple rows, one for each order #.  Then I can work it into the report.

Comment: If your parameter is multivalued you don't have to split it.

Comment: Taking the split out and reverting the parameter to the default, i get an error: ORA--00936 missing expression

Comment: I can then change the where clause to WHERE x.order_no IN (:OrderNo) and manually input orders but returns no results.

Comment: How your parameter is being populated?

Comment: Currently it allows multiple values, which can be selected from a list populated by a query that pulls all order #s from the DB

Comment: Where did you put this expression `=SPLIT(Parameters!OrderNo.Value, ",")`?

Comment: That was in the expression for the dataset parameter

Comment: I think you are using that expression in the `default value` tab of your parameter. Try creating the parameter, in `Available values`use the query, in `default values` use the same query. Now in the dataset you want to use the parameter go to properties / parameters and map the @OrderNo to the report parameter.

Comment: I've kept it really simple and done just that, but now i get the error:
ORA-01797 this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL

Comment: Check [this](http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com.co/2008/06/ora-01797-this-operator-must-be.html)

Comment: When i fix this, then I have the problem where it throws all the addresses into the same spot on one report.  I need each address/order to have its own report.

Comment: I have a bunch of static text boxes on the report.  The only dynamic pieces are a Tablix, and an @OrderNo field at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using a stored procedure with a multi value parameter. What i had to do is create a split string function [Like This One.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
@string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
@delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
SET @string=REPLACE(@string,'(,)','$$')
DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
IF @end = 0 
SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1 

INSERT INTO @output (splitdata) 
VALUES(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start),'$$','(,)')) 
SET @start = @end + 1 
SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start) 

END 
RETURN 
END
```

and in the where clause use it like this.

```
  Where something IN (select *from dbo.fnSplitString('Querying SQL Server',','))
```

Comment: I'm really inexperienced with procs.. where would I put this in an SSRS report?

Comment: Create the function in the DB, then use the where clause I provided in and modify your where clauses that have the multi value parameters in them to looks like it.

Comment: is there a way to apply this split strategy in the current framework, without introducting a proc?